# Inferring a recurrence relation, stairway climbing

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

**Problem**.  Suppose a dog can jump one or two steps of a stairway of $k$ steps.  How many different ways can this dog climb up?  Answer it with a recurrence relation.

**Solution**.  I calculated the number of ways for the first step $n_1 = 1$, and also for second $n_2 = 2$ and third step $n_3 = 3$.  From the pattern, I'm inferring that $n_k = n_{k-1} + n_{k-2}$ and so it seems to be a Fibonacci sequence with the first element chopped off --- 1, 1, 2, 3, ... But I don't consider this a solution because I'm sort of guessing.  What is the reasoning that I could apply here to naturally build this recurrence relation?  How should I think of this to be able to infer it myself?  Must I always guess and prove things by induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did dog get to step $k$? From either step $k-1$ or step $k-2$.

Can it get to stair number $k - 1$ the same way as to $k-2$? No, as it can't get to different steps the same way:)

So, number of ways to get to the step $k$ is sum of number of ways to get to steps $k - 1$ and $k - 2$. Or, in formula, $n_k = n_{k - 1} + n_{k - 2}$.

Comment: That was great!  Very intuitive.  From which steps can it get to step $k$?  That was the important question to ask.  We end up with addition because we have two different ways to get to step $k$.  Marvelous.  Thanks!